# ListViews inside a listiview

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list view in which I have another list view. But i'm not able to scroll the inside list view, can anyone help me in this regard?
The inner List view is getting data from database, so its size will be dynamic? 
i want to display entire list and want to scroll the inner list view or the scroll effect is also fine .

Comment: no i have text box and list view in layout and i'm inflating this layout to another layout which is having another list view. based on inflating layout text box value i'm i'm getting values from database and populating the list view. Now i want entire list view in with values should be displayed

Comment: I would use ExpandableListView. Depending on how much data you will bind, the application might become extremely slow

Answer (score 0):

In general you shouldn't put things that scroll inside things that scroll, if I were you I'd change my design so it doesn't require a listview inside a listview.

I'm not even going to make an attempt at the code required for it but the reason you can't scroll the inner listview is because the outer listview is consuming the touch event.

To send events to the inner listview you need to

1. Intercept the touch event (ACTION_DOWN)
2. Decide which listview its for
3. Send the touch event to that listview

The reason why most people avoid trying this is Step 2 above, it's very difficult to determine what events should be sent to the inner view.

Comment: i dont want to scroll the things inside i want to display all the things to be displayed, if i give size to the inner listview it affects the list view having less data, i.e, it is giving empty space i dnt want to be like this it should be populate dynamically without space

Comment: If you don't need it to scroll then why are you using a listview inside a listview?

Comment: i want ot display the values retrieved from database in the form of list so im using listview im using a base adapter to populate the list view

Comment: Perhaps you should add an image to your question of what you want your UI to do or post some code to help better understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: edit your question, to add code just paste it in, then if the site doesn't display it properly add 4 spaces before each line of code